# What is the best practice to secure cost REST call?

Tags: rest, security, man-in-the-middle

For getting authenticated as a new user over my app, there is a need to make a call to REST function from the mobile app to send SMS or a voice call to the desired device to get a PIN code, this flow costs us money.

The problem is, that we found a lot of false requests by some several hackers over the world.

My question is what is the best practice to solve such security issue ?

Is creating public key and private key enough? or maybe encryption of the body can either solve this issue?

Comment: No, any measures to keep the hackers out are meaningless, as long as you want to keep the legitimate users in. Whatever encryption you add, hackers see and can use it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what about public and private keys ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Public keys are called that for a reason, everybody can see them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev
is Keycloak can solve such problem ?